# Visual studio 2019 crash while attach kernel debugging

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, kernel

Trying to attach the kernel through VS2019, and when I break, the VS (devenv.exe) suddenly crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a nasty bug!

I tried to replace the WDK/SDK, reinstall the VS extension, and reinstall the VS (2022 isn't supporting kernel-debug yet), but nothing helped.

I knew the reason was heap corruption, I had bet the extension, but the real reason was the visual studio window layout. Since I'm syncing my layout with my MS account, it automatically applied, and some window within it cause the crash.

This is a sharing for the very few people that could encounter the same issue.

Comment: oh my god it's actually the window layout, every time I would attach VS with kernel debug it would crash VS.

After connecting kernel debug I went window > reset window layout and it changed the window layout to look like it does when the debugger isn't running.

When I ran my target program on the VM I was connected to I actually hit the breakpoint in my code, instead of crashing VS.

Thank you so much, and I hope this helps anybody else in the same situation.

This was in vs 2019 and I believe same experience in 2022